# How to import lxml xpath functions to default namespace?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

This is a example in [lxml doc](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#regular-expressions-in-xpath):

```
>>> regexpNS = "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
>>> find = etree.XPath("//*[re:test(., '^abc$', 'i')]",
...                    namespaces={'re':regexpNS})

>>> root = etree.XML("<root><a>aB</a><b>aBc</b></root>")
>>> print(find(root)[0].text)
aBc
```

I want to import `re:test()` function to default namespace, so that I can call it without prefix `re:`. How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put a function in the empty function namespace:

```
functionNS = etree.FunctionNamespace(None)
functionNS['test'] = lambda context, nodes, *args: print(context, nodes, args)
```

By doing so, the new `test` function is already registered with the empty namespace prefix, that means you can use it like this:

```
root.xpath("//*[test(., 'arg1', 'arg2')]")
```

Unfortunately the [function](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/1c6084a1754e83c45286fe2b112d2ef327cadc67/src/lxml/extensions.pxi#L497) that is called for `"{http://exslt.org/regular-expressions}test"` isn't available from python, only from within the lxml extension implemented in C, so you can't simply assign it to `functionNS['test']`.

That means you'd need to reimplement it in python to assign it to the empty function namespace...

If that's not worth the trouble for you to spare you typing three characters, you could use this trick to make the `re` prefix for the namespace global:

```
etree.FunctionNamespace("http://exslt.org/regular-expressions").prefix = 're'
```

Then at least you don't need to pass the namespaces dict for each xpath expression.

Comment: I was very excited about the 2nd solution you proposed, but it breaks the behaviour of XPath for me. Namely, if I construct an XPath with some regex without passing the namespace (because it was set like you mentioned), it doesn't work when evaluating the second time. It somehow gets confused, failing with error `XPath function '{}match' not found`. Any idea why ?

Comment: I don't know, can't reproduce this. And you're sure you're using `re:match(...)` everywhere and not `match(...)` without prefix somewhere?

Comment: I created a MWE [here](https://gist.github.com/cipri-tom/f85b246fc8a250ea4debf9178a2732b9) ... **EDIT**: the MWE doesn't work by itself, but it is an exported jupyter notebook. it seems it only fails in the notebook, when the 2 `search` are in different cells

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga - hm, that could be a bug, I'm not sure. Looks liek the registerd prefix is forgotten after the first call of a compiled xpath expression... Unfortunately I can't say more then that. Maybe you should open a new question for this.