# Find Tags inside an XML-Content with Python

Tags: python, xml, if-statement, xml-parsing

I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Normal" />
        <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:hanging="0" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Here are some simple text  like data 01.12.2015, place , country... </w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Normal" />
        <w:ind w:left="0" w:right="0" w:hanging="0" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">01.12.2015 </w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:numPr>
          <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
          <w:numId w:val="1" />
        </w:numPr>
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>09:23. Aksident trafiku me dëme materiale ne mes te veturave Golf 2 dhe Jeep. Te Tre Sheshirat.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:ind w:left="1050" w:right="0" w:hanging="0" />
        <w:jc w:val="center" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>Informuar:PK</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
              <w:checked />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="__Fieldmark__1703_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="1" w:name="__Fieldmark__1703_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="2" w:name="__Fieldmark__1703_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="2" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>,SHME</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="3" w:name="__Fieldmark__1707_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="4" w:name="__Fieldmark__1707_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="5" w:name="__Fieldmark__1707_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="5" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> SHZSH</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="6" w:name="__Fieldmark__1710_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="7" w:name="__Fieldmark__1710_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="8" w:name="__Fieldmark__1710_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="8" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>,Shërbimet tjera</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="9" w:name="__Fieldmark__1713_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="10" w:name="__Fieldmark__1713_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="11" w:name="__Fieldmark__1713_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="11" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:numPr>
          <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
          <w:numId w:val="1" />
        </w:numPr>
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>10:33. Thyerje e shtëpive të banimit ( 2 shtëpi) në  Hajvali në  afërsi të Fsh. Ndërkombëtarë.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:ind w:left="1050" w:right="0" w:hanging="0" />
        <w:jc w:val="center" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>Informuar:PK</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
              <w:checked />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="12" w:name="__Fieldmark__1717_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="13" w:name="__Fieldmark__1717_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="14" w:name="__Fieldmark__1717_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="14" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>,SHME</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="15" w:name="__Fieldmark__1721_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="16" w:name="__Fieldmark__1721_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="17" w:name="__Fieldmark__1721_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="17" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> SHZSH</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="18" w:name="__Fieldmark__1724_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="19" w:name="__Fieldmark__1724_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="20" w:name="__Fieldmark__1724_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="20" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>,Shërbimet tjera</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="21" w:name="__Fieldmark__1727_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="22" w:name="__Fieldmark__1727_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="23" w:name="__Fieldmark__1727_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="23" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:numPr>
          <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
          <w:numId w:val="1" />
        </w:numPr>
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" />
          <w:lang w:eastAsia="ja-JP" />
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>11:16. Shpërthim i gypit të uj</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" />
          <w:lang w:eastAsia="ja-JP" />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>ësjellësit në Rr. “Ekrem Rexha”. Lagjja Kalabria.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:ind w:left="1050" w:right="0" w:hanging="0" />
        <w:jc w:val="center" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:numPr>
          <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
          <w:numId w:val="1" />
        </w:numPr>
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" />
          <w:lang w:eastAsia="ja-JP" />
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" />
          <w:lang w:eastAsia="ja-JP" />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>13:19. Mungesë e ujit të pijshëm në fsh. Miradi e Eperme – Fushë Kosovë.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:ind w:left="1050" w:right="0" w:hanging="0" />
        <w:jc w:val="center" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>Informuar:PK</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="24" w:name="__Fieldmark__1747_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="25" w:name="__Fieldmark__1747_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="26" w:name="__Fieldmark__1747_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="26" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>,SHME</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="27" w:name="__Fieldmark__1751_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="28" w:name="__Fieldmark__1751_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="29" w:name="__Fieldmark__1751_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="29" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> SHZSH</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="30" w:name="__Fieldmark__1754_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="31" w:name="__Fieldmark__1754_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="32" w:name="__Fieldmark__1754_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="32" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>,Shërbimet tjera</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
              <w:checked />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="33" w:name="__Fieldmark__1757_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="34" w:name="__Fieldmark__1757_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="35" w:name="__Fieldmark__1757_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="35" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:numPr>
          <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
          <w:numId w:val="1" />
        </w:numPr>
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>14:42. Aksident trafiku me dëme materiale  ne mes te veturave Opell dhe Kia . dardania te santea.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:ind w:left="1050" w:right="0" w:hanging="0" />
        <w:jc w:val="center" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>Informuar:PK</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
              <w:checked />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="36" w:name="__Fieldmark__1761_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="37" w:name="__Fieldmark__1761_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="38" w:name="__Fieldmark__1761_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="38" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>,SHME</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="39" w:name="__Fieldmark__1765_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="40" w:name="__Fieldmark__1765_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="41" w:name="__Fieldmark__1765_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="41" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> SHZSH</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="42" w:name="__Fieldmark__1768_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="43" w:name="__Fieldmark__1768_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="44" w:name="__Fieldmark__1768_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="44" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>,Shërbimet tjera</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="" />
            <w:enabled />
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0" />
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto />
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:instrText>FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="45" w:name="__Fieldmark__1771_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="46" w:name="__Fieldmark__1771_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="47" w:name="__Fieldmark__1771_516377085" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="47" />
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:numPr>
          <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
          <w:numId w:val="1" />
        </w:numPr>
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>15:49. Vjedhje në lokalin “ Gruda Hony Shop” Në Rr. “Tring Smajli”.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing" />
        <w:tabs>
          <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1290" w:leader="none" />
          <w:tab w:val="center" w:pos="5040" w:leader="none" />
        </w:tabs>
        <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="360" />
        <w:ind w:left="1050" w:right="0" w:hanging="0" />
        <w:jc w:val="center" />
        <w:rPr />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr>
      <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId2" />
      <w:type w:val="nextPage" />
      <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" />
      <w:pgMar w:left="1080" w:right="900" w:header="0" w:top="1440" w:footer="720" w:bottom="1440" w:gutter="0" />
      <w:pgNumType w:fmt="decimal" />
      <w:formProt w:val="false" />
      <w:textDirection w:val="lrTb" />
      <w:docGrid w:type="default" w:linePitch="360" w:charSpace="4294965247" />
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

On this XML I have couples of `<w:p>  </w:p>` There are some `<w:p>` `Description` tags that contains checkbox tag after them and some that are empty.
For each `<w:p>` I need to create a JSON object and store it in a list.

I need to find `<w:p>` tags to take text inside `<w:t>` and then to continue to another `<w:p>` tag to see if it contains checkbox, if yes then to take `<w:t>` value the JSON will look like this:

```
json['description'] = description
json['checkbox_text'] = checkbox
```

else if the tag after `Description` tag contain no checkbox  then the JSON  will contain only one element:

```
json['description'] = description
```

My code looks like this:

```
results = []
    default_positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('w:p', xml_content)]
        jsonobj = {}
        for position in default_positions:
        if .. :
            //code
            json['description'] = description
            json['checkbox_text'] = checkbox
        else:
            //code
            json['description'] = description
```

EDIT:

If i use lxml to do this this:

```
all_namespace={'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main', 
       'o':'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' ,
       'r':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships',
       'v':'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml',
       'w10':'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word',
       'wp':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing'}


mydoc = zipfile.ZipFile('data/test.docx')
xmlcontent = mydoc.read('word/document.xml')
document = etree.XML(xmlcontent)

json_list=[]
for p_el in document.xpath('//w:p[.//w:t]', namespaces={'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}):
    desc_els = p_el.xpath('./w:r/w:t', namespaces={'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'})
    if desc_els:
        regexList = [r'(^\d\d:\d\d*)', r'(^\d\.\d\d:\d\d*)',r'(^\d\d\d\d:\d*)' ,r'(^\d\d\.\d\d:\d\d*)',r'(^\d\d\.\s\d\d:\d\d*)',r'(^\d\.\s\d\d:\d\d*)',r'(^\d\.\s\d\d\d\d:\d\d*)']
        for regex in regexList:
            if re.match( regex, desc_els[0].text, flags=0):
                new_json_obj = {}
                new_json_obj['description'] = desc_els[0].text
                checkbox_els = p_el.xpath('//w:r/w:checkBox', namespaces={'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'})
                if checkbox_els:
                    print "THIS" , checkbox_els[0].text
                    if p_el.xpath('.//w:checked'):
                        new_json_obj['checkbox_state'] = 'True'
                    else:
                        new_json_obj['checkbox_state'] = 'False'
                json_list.append(new_json_obj)
print json.dumps(json_list)
```

As as result i get this:

```
[{"description": "1. 07:48 Description 1"}, {"description": "1. 07:48 Description 2"} , {"description": "1. 07:48 Description 3"}]
```

That part of checking if in next `w:p` tag exists a checkbox that is checked is not working?

Comment: In the future, edit your old posts rather than deleting and recreating them. Once or twice isn't a problem, but the automated systems will flag too much deletion and recreation, which will eventually lead to rate limiting, and then a ban.

Comment: BTW, right now, what you're providing here isn't valid XML because it doesn't provide a `xmlns:w` tag, which I assume your real data/document contains. Consider making your sample data more complete.

Comment: Actually -- this is an Office doc? Then the namespace is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml`.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the existing xml parsing libraries? There's [xml processing capabilities](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.html) built into the standard python modules, or [lxml](http://lxml.de/) works well.

Comment: BTW, what exactly do you want to fill in `checkbox_text` if something contains a checkbox?

Comment: @JCVanHamme, that was pointed out in comments to the prior (now deleted) iteration of this question -- which, as far as I can tell, was an exact duplicate of the new one; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010478/find-tags-inside-an-xml-with-python

Comment: When trimming down XML, try to be sure it's still syntactically valid. In this case, that required putting some closing tags back in.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this the right way might look something like the following:

```
import lxml.etree
import json

nsmap={'w': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml'}

tree = lxml.etree.parse(your_file_object)

json_list=[]
new_json_obj = {}

# find w:p entities that contain w:t
for p_el in tree.xpath('//w:p[.//w:t]', nsmap=nsmap):
    desc_els = p_el.xpath('./w:r/w:t', nsmap=nsmap)
    if desc_els:
        new_json_obj['description'] = desc_els[0].text()
    checkbox_els = p_el.xpath('following-sibling::w:p//w:checkbox', nsmap=nsmap)
    if checkbox_els:
        if p_el.xpath('.//w:enabled'):
            new_json_obj['checkbox_state'] = True
        else:
            new_json_obj['checkbox_state'] = False
    json_list.append(new_json_obj)
    new_json_obj = {}

print json.dumps(json_list)
```

Comment: thank you for your help! Actually the xml content I get by zipping  .docx word files

Comment: ...also, if it's actually `http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main` rather than `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml`, you'll need to change the `nsmap` in the code appropriately.

Comment: Mine is:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main i replaced nsmap.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest running the commands in this code in the REPL and inspecting what they return to get a better idea of the logic and how it works.

Comment: please check my edited part of my question, if you have any idea?

Comment: ...regex list? Please stop trying to use regular expressions for XML. You can write an xpath expression which will look for the pattern of digits you want. Also, there's no need for a list of regular expressions there; you can write only a single regex equivalent to the four.

Comment: That is only to take only events that start with numbers so in that way i dont need to include other parts of XML that i don't need?

Comment: i have a lot of cases but here is only one so for that i created a list of regex

Comment: Yes, but you don't *need* a list of regexes; you can build just one. Consider the `{min,max}` repetition operator for runs of characters, and the `|` to provide multiple alternatives. And even then, you can tell the XPath engine to run that regex, so you don't need to put it in Python.

Comment: thank you for your advice, i will try to implement it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2756994/14122 for moving the regex evaluation into the XPath.

Comment: ok what about checkbox value I was trying to find by splitting tags into two parts, first to take the description and second to search for checked tag but I couldn't do it, can you help me?

Comment: BTW, some of the changes you made to this code revert intentional decisions. Using the native Python booleans `True` and `False` rather than strings `'True'` and `'False'` means that the JSON serializer will change them to native JavaScript/JSON booleans `true` and `false`, rather than strings `"True"` and `"False"`.

Comment: ...as for your continued follow-up questions, I may look at them when I have time. That said, generally speaking, amending follow-up questions into a question is considered poor form (a "question" that actually contains more than one question at its heart being "too broad", that being a close reason).

Comment: i just tried to make it work, about those changing true and false, i wanted to save in database which tag is checked for that.. anyway i will try again .. thank you for your time

Comment: Ahh. I didn't grok that you want to look for the checkbox in the **next** tag. That means you want to go through the `following-sibling` axis.

Comment: check I attached a screenshot how .docx file looks like? U can understand better if u see it

Comment: did u checked the picture  that I attached?

Comment: Bluntly -- I'm here to build a better Q&A knowledge base. Spending an excess of time answering questions that aren't particularly useful to anyone but the person asking isn't a particularly effective contribution to that goal. That said, did you see the edit suggesting `following-sibling::w:p//w:checkbox`?